# Obtaining e-mail address at registration

Tags: email, validation

In a registration form the user is asked for his e-mail address. The e-mail address will be validated for the correct format (e.g. at the least contains <kbd>@</kbd>) and I'm considering checking if it's already registered. Would this pose a security risk as it would allow attackers to verify e-mail addresses of users with accounts? If yes how can the threat be mitigated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this kind of leak, you could also begin the registration process by asking for the e-mail. After entering it, you would send an e-mail with a link so that the user could continue with the registration process. If the e-mail was already registered, you would send an e-mail saying that.

That way, only the owner of the e-mail could register.

**Drawbacks**:

- probably the real, common users will get bored by having so much steps to register.
- in very few cases simple revealing that an e-mail is already registered in a site is a problem, specially because it's easy to register at any site providing any e-mail that you want. You'll just won't receive the e-mail to activate your account, but *in general* the site will link the account / username to that e-mail.

Comment: But how can this solution be implemented? I must save

Comment: You must save the username/ password, the email, and the unique link (one link to each username/email)...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154031/design-dielema-if-e-mail-address-already-used-send-email-e-mail-address-alread?noredirect=1#comment26591436_18154031

Comment: that's the problem! I'm saving to the database an account I know won't exist.

Comment: ops, I'll comment on stackoverflow then...

Answer (score 3):

Using a username rather than an e-mail address is one method or use a combination of both for security sensitive stuff like password resets.  This renders discovering a particular e-mail address exists less useful if both a username and e-mail are needed.

It isn't such a big deal to leak the fact a particular e-mail address exists in most cases unless privacy is a large concern in which case using usernames exclusively for uniqueness might be preferred.  Alternately, you could allow the account to appear to be created, but send an e-mail to the e-mail address given stating that an account already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen more sites change the response to accounts having been created (notification), to something like: "If the account exists, an e-mail will be sent" versus: "*there is no such account*" (which allows someone registering to know whether or not an account already exists) If you are looking to stop "account enumeration," give OWASP a look: "[Testing for User Enumeration and Guessable User Account](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_%28OWASP-AT-002%29)"